# UI too slow to be inflated, causing application to be slow

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a constraint layout inside a ScrollView. This ConstraintLayout is supposed to be a parent for other Views that will be added into it, as shown:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/generated_main_constraint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I try to add view to this ConstraintLayout, I inflate the view from XML, with the following code:

```
(ConstraintLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.box_npcs, MAIN_CONSTRAINT, false);
```

This layout is defined in XML1 (end of the question).

Then I add TextViews with information to this Layout's LinearLayout, for that I use a programatically created TextView and add it into the layout

```
linearLayout.addView(new TextView("Foo"));
```

With that setup, I add this box to the main constraint layout.

The problem is: **When I try to add more than 5 views, it takes a long time to proccess the UI**, taking up to 5 seconds on the max amount of view to be added (50).

**How can I add Complex Views to a ConstraintLayout in a way that it doesn't lag when trying to add the views?**

XML1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/box_npcs"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/npcImage"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="88dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/layoutInformation"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/layoutInformation"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/camera" />

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutInformation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:maxWidth="280dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/npcImage"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/top_priority"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:text="DummyTextIsDummy"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_default"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="normal"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout_high_highest_normal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/top_priority"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_priority" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Images for examples:
Each 'box' in this screen is a box in the Main Constraint Layout.
Each TextLine is a different TextView added to the LinearLayout
[image]

Comment: you should show your `adding views` code. the slow progress is not adding view progress .

Answer (score 2):

What is the android version in your test device?

A few days ago, I found a problem.

If I use two or more `ConstraintLayouts` in Android 5 or 6, it will be slow.
When I used the Android Studio CPU Profiler, I saw the `com.android.internal.policy.impl.phonewindow$decorview.onmeasure` spent much time.

So I tried to use `LinearLayout`, and the problem was solved.

I think `ConstraintLayout` in Support Library is not friendly for Android 5 or 6.